# Get Operational log EventLog fails

Tags: c#, event-log

I get `InvalidOperationException` when I run this code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var aLog = new EventLog("Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational");
    EventLogEntry entry;
    var entries = aLog.Entries;
    var stack = new Stack<EventLogEntry>();
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
    {
        entry = entries[i];
        stack.Push(entry);
    }
    entry = stack.Pop();// only display the last record
    Console.WriteLine("[Index]\t" + entry.Index +
                        "\n[EventID]\t" + entry.InstanceId +
                        "\n[TimeWritten]\t" + entry.TimeWritten +
                        "\n[MachineName]\t" + entry.MachineName +
                        "\n[Source]\t" + entry.Source +
                        "\n[UserName]\t" + entry.UserName +
                        "\n[Message]\t" + entry.Message +
                        "\n---------------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Exception says that:

> **Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational** doesn't exist on this computer

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Updated**

Since you are using `EventLog` class, the valid "categories" (for sure this is not the correct word to name it...) for your constructor must be ***Application***, ***System*** or any other Log Name available under ***Windows Log*** tree, not under ***Applications And Services Log*** tree.

```
const string LogName = "Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational";
var query = new EventLogQuery(LogName, PathType.LogName, "*[System/Level=2]");

using (var reader = new EventLogReader(query))
{
    var currentEvent = reader.ReadEvent();
    while (currentEvent != null)
    {
        // Do your stuff here...

        // Read next event.
        currentEvent = reader.ReadEvent();
    }
}
```

This snippet code works for me.

Remember to run this under **elevated privileges**. If not, you'll receive an Unauthorized exception throw.

### **First Answer**

Because you are initializing your `EventLog` class with a category that doesn't exists.

Typical valid categories would be **Application**, **System**, etc.

The single parameter constructor for `EventLog` refers to a log of the registry. [[^]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9hdxtte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I want to access date and time of computer's shutdown like described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/72420/how-to-use-event-viewer-to-find-your-pcs-boot-time/). Log Name is `Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational`, not `System` nor `Application`.

Comment: @patryk.beza, please review my answer to check if my solution works for you, or, at least, it gives you an idea of how to fix your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I want to use the `EventLog` class like OP was trying to do, not the `EventLogReader` class. I have the same issue as OP.